# Is there a UDEV rule to detect decrypted and mounted LUKS partition?

Tags: linux, backup, mount, luks, udev

I have a LUKS partition on an external hard drive. When I plug it in, Ubuntu 22.04 **automatically decrypts** the partition and **mounts** it, since I saved the passphrase to the keyring. I would like to **run a backup script** when this happens.

This did **not** work:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="uuid-of-the-decrypted-partition", RUN+="/path/to/backup/script"
```

Is there a way to detect in UDEV when the partition is mounted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, udev doesn't handle mounts (they're not "devices"). It can react to the volume being unlocked (as this creates a "mapper" device) but not to it being mounted (which neither adds a device nor "changes" it).

Create a systemd service that runs your backup script, then add it as a dependency of the .mount unit `run-media-whatever.mount` corresponding to where the disk is mounted. (Fstab entries create real .mount units, but virtual .mount units exist regardless of what caused the filesystem to be mounted, so this will work even with plain GNOME auto-mounts.)

For a backup script, the service should generally be `Type=oneshot`.

The dependency from the .mount unit to your service can be added with `systemctl enable` and an `[Install]` section (use `systemd-escape -p` to have it output the correct .mount name for a path, or just find it in `systemctl -t mount`). If you want the service to be triggered by multiple paths, you can list multiple units in [Install].

```
[Unit]
Description=System backup

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/cron.backup

[Install]
WantedBy=run-media-backup.mount
```

After `systemctl enable`, this service will be run every time /run/media/backup is mounted.

If your auto-mounts result in a path that's not unique enough – add an /etc/fstab entry that specifies a custom path for each UUID (GNOME automount will honor fstab; you can even do it through GNOME Disks' "Mount Options"); alternatively make the script itself check what was mounted (using findmnt) and have it simply exit if the filesystem UUID is wrong.

Note that you would need a service *anyway,* as you cannot run long-running scripts from udev rules (anymore) – those would need to be run indirectly no matter what (through `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}` if you were dealing with a device).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for this. Just a question: Will this run in every mount? I'd like to run the script only on specific UUIDs.

Comment: It runs on every mount *at that specific path* only (or paths, multiple are allowed). If the path isn't very unique – add an /etc/fstab entry that specifies a custom path for each UUID (GNOME automount will honor fstab; you can even do it through GNOME Disks' "Mount Options"). Alternatively, make the script itself check what was mounted (using findmnt) and have it simply exit if the filesystem UUID is wrong.

Comment: I tested it and it did what I wanted to do. Thanks for pointing me to `systemd` virtual mounts.